# Find the maximum value of $a + b$

Tags: number-theory, inequality

Let a,b,c,d be real numbers such that $ 0 \le a≤b≤c≤d $ and
$c+d =a^2 +b^2 +c^2 + d^2 =1$. Find the maximum value of $a+b$

This was taken from the $2017$ IMC held in India

I attempted to solve this by showing that $ (c+d)^2 =1=c+d$ thus $2cd = a^2 + b^2 $ but Im not sure what to do next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) is a general way to attack this problem.

However...  We have the system \begin{align}
\max a+b & \text{ such that } \\
c+d &= 1  \\
a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 &= 1  \\
0 &\leq a \leq b \leq c \leq d  \text{.}
\end{align}
The objective function and the first two constraints are unchanged under exchange of $c$ and $d$, suggesting $c = d$, which is compatible with the remaining constraint.  So $2c = 1$, $c = d = 1/2$.  This gives the reduced system
\begin{align}
\max a+b & \text{ such that } \\
a^2+b^2 &= 1/2  \\
0 &\leq a \leq b \leq 1/2  \text{.}
\end{align}
Again, the objective and first constraint are unchanged by exchange of $a$ and $b$ and then $a = b$ is compatible with the remaining constraint, so $a = b = 1/2$ is the solution.  By symmetry, these assemble into the only solution, 
$$  a = b = c = d = 1/2  \text{,}  $$
so the maximum of $a+b$ is $1$.

(In terms of Lagrange multipliers, we first fin the point on the $c+d=1$ constraint where the objective gradient is perpendicular to the constraint.  Then we find the point on the squared constraint where the objective gradient is perpendicular to the level sets of the constraint.  (The constraint is the unit sphere, so we find where the gradient is radially outward.)  The Lagrangian satisfies both of the exchange symmetries we used above.  In full pedantry, we should ensure that we did not find a minimum, but this is a triviality for a linear objective.)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Use the obvious $(x+y)^2\leqslant 2(x^2+y^2)$ twice to get $(a+b)^2\leqslant 2(a^2+b^2)=2(1-c^2-d^2)\leqslant 2(1-\frac12)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that we are given $c$ and $d$. Then, $a=\sqrt{1-c^2-d^2-b^2}$. Finding the max of $\sqrt{1-c^2-d^2-b^2}+b$ is trivial - simply find the derivative with respect to $b$ and find where it equals $0$. It can be seen that the max is at $a = b = \sqrt{\frac{1-c^2-d^2}{2}}$. This means that $a+b = 2\sqrt{\frac{1-c^2-d^2}{2}}$

Now to make $a+b$ as large as possible, $1-c^2-d^2$ must be as large as possible. Since $d = 1-c$, this can be simplified to $1-c^2-(1-c)^2 = -2c^2+2c$. The max of this is at $c=1/2$, which means that $d = 1/2$. The max of $a+b$ is then $2\sqrt{\frac{1-(\frac{1}{2})^2-(\frac{1}{2})^2}{2}} = 2\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}} = 2*\frac{1}{2} = 1$. This also logically makes sense, as all four variables are equal to $1/2$.